# Find row in sheet for matching cell content

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2010

I'm trying to make the following function to work. I need to give it a sheet name, a column to search its cells and a condition, and when cell contents match, return row number

```
Function findRow(worksheetname As Worksheet, searchColumn As Integer, condition As String) As Integer

Dim i As Integer           ' Integer used in 'For' loop

findRow = 0

For i = 1 To Rows.count
    If Worksheets(worksheetname).Cells(i, searchColumn).Value = condition Then

        ' A match has been found to the supplied string
        ' Store the current row number and exit the 'For' Loop
        findRow = i
        Exit For

    End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Trying to call it like this:

```
row = findRow(Application.Worksheets(ClustersInfo), 1, clusters(clusterid))
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: "Subscript out of range" message...

Comment: Worksheets(worksheetname) should just be worksheetname